# Specific query gives me trouble

Tags: postgresql, query, pgadmin

I'm supposed to run this query in PGadmin:

```
SELECT
    n2.cpr, 
    n2.adresseringsnavn,
    n2."fødselsdato" AS foedselsdato, 
    n2.morcpr,
    n1.mor_navn,
    n2.farcpr,
    n3.far_navn
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM data.cpr_aktivkom_geoview WHERE
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x' OR
        cpr = 'x') n2
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT cpr, adresseringsnavn AS mor_navn
    FROM data.cpr_aktivkom_geoview) n1
ON n2.morcpr = n1.cpr
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT cpr, adresseringsnavn AS far_navn
    FROM data.cpr_aktivkom_geoview) n3
ON n2.farcpr = n3.cpr
ORDER BY n2."fødselsdato" asc
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 2:     n2.cpr, 
              ^ 

SQL state: 42601
Character: 14
```

What is the problem with the dot after the n2's, n1's and n3's?

Comment: Nothing obvious except for the duplicate `WHERE` clauses. Are you executing exactly this, or along with other queries?

Comment: What happens if you run just the inner query of the `n2` alias (the query against `data.cpr_aktivkom_geoview`)? Agreed with Charlieface too, are you running **exactly** this query or did you change it and / or are running other queries with it?...it's odd that the inner query of `n2` has the same `OR` clause repeated 11 times.

Comment: Check for invisible nonstandard characters in your copypaste, like unbreakable space etc. A good way to do this is to paste in a text editor.

Comment: Very likely, you are making a mistake using pgAdmin: make sure that *only* your statement is in the query window. My guess is that you have some text before the statement in the window.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, it’s because the `SELECT` is on its own line. Try this.

```
SELECT n2.cpr,
       n2.addresseringsnavn,
. . .
```